# PASSWORD() like functionality for MySQL 8.0, pluggable authentication

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

Before pluggable authentication, with the [PASSWORD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) function, I was able to

1. create the hashed password string, as stored in mysql.user from
   a cleartext password,
2. verify if a cleartext password matches the
   hashed password in mysql.user.

Is there a way to do that with pluggable authentication, without going into details of authentication plugins?
Something like

```
GET_HASH_STRING_FROM_PASSWORD(password, authplugin)
VERIFY_PASSWORD(password, hash_string, authplugin)
```

Comment: Did you happen to figure this out?